# Corpora for extractive summaries

Tags: computational-linguistics, corpora, resource-request, summarization

I am looking for corpora of extractive summaries. I am mostly interested in English, and any type of document.

Answer (score 1):

A [list of extractive summary corpora](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Does_anyone_know_of_an_annotated_corpus_for_extractive_summarization) can be found over on ResearchGate.

Additionally, a quick search revealed multiple papers on supervised extractive summarization (for example, [this one](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1599205)), using the [DUC](http://www-nlpir.nist.gov/projects/duc/data.html) or [TAC](https://tac.nist.gov/data/index.html) datasets. Although I've not personally worked with these datasets, if they're used in supervised learning approaches they should contain the information you need.